# Google Cloud Platform: Quotas

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota

Why can't I change a quota limit? Yesterday my server stopped accepting requests due to some Backend-Service quota expired
[Editing quotas gives a blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOU5n.png)

Comment: Too few information to help you!! Add more detalis!

Comment: You can request a quota increase [1], [2], However you need to know what quota is causing the issue. If you have a generated error, you can navigate to operations > logs viewer and paste that error using advanced filter. This way logs viewer [3] will query all generated logs with that error.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas
[2] https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota
[3] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview